# Problema con "if", "and" y "or"

Tags: php, condiciones

Tengo un array que me trae ciertos datos. Necesito asegurarme que solo se ingresen esos datos. Para ello, simplemente los comparo en un `if` así:

```php
if (trim($datos[NIVEL]) != trim("TACTICO") || trim("OPERATIVO")) {
    $errorMensaje[$key+2][] = "El campo ".$arrayEncabezado[NIVEL]." no existe en base de datos";
    $has_error = true;
}
```

El problema es que solo me está filtrando por táctico.  Si en `$datos[NIVEL]` tengo operativo me muestra el  error cuando no debe entrar al ciclo, porque justamente esas son las validaciones que necesito.

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da?

Comment: Primero ten en cuenta que cuando tienes una sentencia que sigue a OR se analizará a no ser que la previa lo haga innecesario (cumple la condición de entrada en el `if`). Luego, estas usando operadores de comparación y lógicos, no tienen la misma precedencia, deberías anidar las diferentes comparaciones usando paréntesis, p.e. `if ((trim($datos[NIVEL]) != trim("TACTICO")) || trim("OPERATIVO")) {` 
VIendo la línea anterior parece que tienes varios errores llamando al array con los datos, prueba con: `if ((trim($datos['NIVEL']) != trim($datos['TACTICO])) || trim($datos['OPERATIVO])) {`

Answer (score 0):

Estás fallando la ejecución del `IF`

```
if (trim($datos[NIVEL]) != trim("TACTICO") || trim("OPERATIVO")) { <- ACA ESTAS FALLANDO
    ...
}
```

Para ejecutar un `OR` - `||`, tienes que hacerlo del siguiente modo

```
if(variable1 == condicion2 || variable2 == condicion2){...}
```

Por lo que tu `IF` deberia cambiar a esto:

```
if (trim($datos[NIVEL]) != trim("TACTICO") || trim($datos[NIVEL]) != trim("OPERATIVO")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: tampoco me funciono eso, pero ya logre resolverlo, con una funcion. gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Recuerda agregar tu respuesta acá para contestarla y cerrarla